# Подскажите как по клику узнать ключ?

Tags: reactjs

```js
click(e){
    console.log(e.key);
}


    
render() {
    let array = this.state.array;
    let unit = array.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                <a key={index}
                style={{display:"block"}}
                onClick={this.click.bind(this)}
                >Hello, {item}</a>
                )
            });
```

Как по клику посмотреть ключ ссылки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `key` используется для внутренней работы reactjs, поэтому получить его нельзя. Но можно сохранить индекс в другое свойство.

Например:

```
let unit = array.map((item, index) => {
            return (
            <a key={index}
            my_key={index}
            style={{display:"block"}}
            onClick={this.click.bind(this)}
            >Hello, {item}</a>
            )
        });
```

Посмотреть можно так:

```
click(e){
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('my_key'));
}
```